how can I retrieve Photoshop artlayer names from specific sub-layerset into an array?
I have a Photoshop PSD document which has a layerset named “Flags“. “Flags” has a sub-layerset called “LEFT-Flags“ which itself contains artlayers, each with a national flag image. The number of these artlayers is currently around 40 - but will increase over time.
As an ExtendScript newbie, may I ask how - in ExtendScript - can I extract the NAMES of each of the artlayers to an array please?

Basically it can be done this way:
var layers = app.activeDocument
    .layerSets['Flags']
    .layerSets['LEFT-Flags']
    .artLayers;

var names = [];
for (var i=0; i<layers.length; i++) names.push(layers[i].name);

// put the names into a txt file and open the file
var f = File(Folder.temp + '/layers_names.txt');
f.open('w');
f.encoding = 'UTF-8';
f.write(names.join('\n'));
f.close();
f.execute();

The array names will contain the names.
But I don't know what you want to do with this array. Do you mean to save it as a TXT file?

That is brilliant Yuri!  It works!Thanks so much! In fact, I only need the first half of your code as I don’t need to save it as a text file. The layer names all end with the country name of the flag concerned. I’m going to be using split and substr to filter down the array elements to those beginning with a user-selected initial letter. (Well, the “user“ is me really). To date I’ve had to hard code the array each time a new flag is added to the sub-layerset. Your code will enable me to create the array on the fly.

Overnight (I’m in England) it has occurred to me that perhaps you meant you were interested to know what I’m using this FOR? I’m producing customised thumbnail images for an Ancestry family tree – including (amongst other things) small flag images that show the person’s birth and death countries. If my master PSD doesn't  already have the flag requested it opens onto a ‘flags of the world’ website to fetch it. Using the array and only having to input the country’s initial letter avoids typing errors - which I’m prone to! Chris.

Wow. Sounds like a lot of advanced coding. O though you’re a newbie. Good luck with your project!

Thanks Yuri. I am a beginner in Extenscript. (Most of what I’ve done to date is with heavy use of ScriptListener. I think I’ve prob got a lot of unnecessary coding as a consequence!). I have though been using ObjectPal for Paradox databases since the 1980s (and still do - despite it being antiquated) so I think I understand the general principles okay. My original submission to Staging Ground mentioned all this but I was asked to pare it back to the essential question I was wanting help with. Have to say, much of what this site deals with is way above my head! (Then again, I am in my 70s…). C.

Scripting with sub-layers is often a pain. One of the best things to do is loop over the whole Photoshop file - which can get slow on how may layers you have. -  You might find it useful:
// group layer vegetables
var allLayers = new Array();
var theLayers = collectAllLayers(app.activeDocument, 0);

function doStuff(alayer)
{
   var currentLayerName = alayer.name;
   alert(currentLayerName);
}


// function collect all layers
function collectAllLayers (theParent, level)
{
   for (var m = theParent.layers.length - 1; m >= 0; m--)
   {
      var theLayer = theParent.layers[m];
      
      // apply the function to layersets;
      if (theLayer.typename == "ArtLayer")

      {
         // find the art layers
         doStuff(theLayer)
      }
      else
      {
         allLayers.push(level + theLayer.name);
         collectAllLayers(theLayer, level + 1)
      }
   }
} 

As for processing a folder, you'll want something like this:
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // OFF


var sourcePath = "C:\\flags"; // Or whatever. Location of flag folders

var myFiles = []; // list of all files collected
var myFileList = get_sub_folders(sourcePath)


for(var i = 0; i < myFileList.length; i++)
{

  // load the files one by one
  // alert(myFileList[i])
  open_it(myFileList[i]);

  // process flag here
  // do something
}



// function GET SUB FOLDERS (folder path)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
function get_sub_folders(theFolder)
{
  theFolder = Folder(theFolder);

  var myFileList = theFolder.getFiles();

  for (var i = 0; i < myFileList.length; i++)
  {
    var myFile = myFileList[i];
    if (myFile instanceof Folder)
    {
      get_sub_folders(myFile);
    }
    else if (myFile instanceof File)
    {
      myFiles.push(myFile);
    }
  }

  return myFiles;
}


// function OPEN FILE (filenameandpath)
// --------------------------------------------------------
function open_it(filenameandpath)
{
  var fileRef = new File(filenameandpath)
  if (fileRef.exists)
  //open that doc
  {
    app.open(fileRef);
  }
  else
  {
    alert("error opening " + filenameandpath)
  }
}


If you want the whole thing to start from the first folder use this:
var sourcePath = "C:\\flags\\Flags - A"; // Location of FIRST flag folders

var theFolders = get_flag_folders(sourcePath);


for(var i = 0; i < theFolders.length; i++)
{

  // load the files one by one
  var theFolder = Folder(theFolders[i]);

  var myFileList = theFolder.getFiles();

  //open the only (and therefore first) file
  // if there are more create a loop over myFileList
  open_it(myFileList[0]);

  // process flag here
  // do something
}


function get_flag_folders(sourcefolder)
{
  var flagDir = "Flags - ";
  var flagFolders = ["A", "B", "C"]; // add the alphabet here
  var foldersArr = [];

  var source = sourcefolder.substring(0, sourcefolder.lastIndexOf("\\"));

  for(var i = 0; i < flagFolders.length; i++)
  {
    foldersArr.push(source + "\\" + flagDir + flagFolders[i]);
  }
  return foldersArr;
}


Thanks, Ghoul Fool. Only just seen your response but I will check it out. Whilst the dimensions of my Photoshop file is very small (176x170 pixels), you are right, I do have a lot of layers in it, so – from what you say - it could be an issue. For the moment though, the code from @Yuri Khristich  does seem to be the solution to my current need. Best, C

Ghoul Fool and @Yuri Khristich. Okay, so I wondered whether I might be able to bypass the lack of speed - and yes, it IS slow - by taking the flags out of the main document and making 26 folders (Flags - A”, “Flags - B” etc) on my file system and placing individual flag images as separate tiny JPEGs (named Australia.jpg, Austria.jpg etc) in the appropriate lettered folder. The plan was to create the array of countries by accessing the jpg names in the relevant lettered folder. But now I can’t see how to access a folder’s files with ExtendScript! Is it possible? Thank you, C.

Thanks for going to such trouble again Goul Fool! Now that I've got the flags in a folder for each initial letter though, I don't think I need to look in sub-folders any more do I? Can I not just declare the source as "D:\...\Flags\Flags - A" [or whatever letter is needed] and populate the array from that one folder's files? (Preferably minus the ".jpg" extension. eg. "Andora, Austria" etc). The User then chooses from the array and I open the one flag concerned. I'm guessing that this is much simpler code and have tried (for hours!) to adapt yours myself. But without success...  :^/

Sorry, I don't think I can have explained what I was after very well as I couldn't get that to work. HOWEVER. I think I've managed to write something simple that does it. (By combining elements of your code Ghoul Fool and that of @Yuri Khristich ). How do I post the code here though? Do I click the "Answer Your Question" button?

That's one way of doing it, yes.

Is there another way? Only I tried clicking "Answer Your Question" button, pasted in my Extendscript code and it seemed to jumble everything up (not looking like what you've  been entering).

OK. Managed to do it.

var userChosenInitial = "J";  
// (This will already have been provided by the User).  

// So the path to the relevant folder is:  
var sourceFolder = "D:\\OneDrive\\Family-Tree\\Family-Tree-Images\\Flags\\Flags - " + userChosenInitial;  
// The "Flags - J" folder has just three flag jpgs: Jamaica.jpg, Japan.jpg and Jordan.jpg  

// Save the specified folder path as a Folder type:  
var theFolder = Folder(sourceFolder);  

var pathAndFileList = theFolder.getFiles();  
// (getFiles() gets the entire path too).  

// Prepare an array to hold the country names:  
var   countriesList = [];  

for(var i = 0; i < pathAndFileList.length; i++)  
{
// Trim the path out leaving "Jamaica.jpg,Japan.jpg,Jordan.jpg":  
fileName = pathAndFileList[i].name;  

// Trim off the ".jpg" file extensions:  
countryName = fileName.substr(0,fileName.length - 4);  

// Pass the resulting country name to the waiting countries array:  
countriesList.push(countryName);  
}  
// View resulting array:  
alert(countriesList, "Countries with the initial \"" + userChosenInitial + "\"");  
// (Displays: "Jamaica,Japan,Jordan")  

